# Is it possible to include snippets from file in snipmate

Tags: arduino, vim

I am using the [vim-snipmate](http://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate) addon with these [snippets](https://github.com/honza/snipmate-snippets).

I am currently in the process of creating a snippet file for Arduino. I realized that all the snippets for the c language also holds good for Arduino.

Instead of just copy pasting them, I am thinking of including the entire c file and then just add Arduino specific parts.

So my question is, is it possible to include snippets from other file into your snippet file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(I found the answer to this question, after searching the documentation of the snipmate Plugin)

I can't include a snippet file in another snippet file, but I can include more than one snippet for a certain file type. I have declared the following in my .vimrc now and it works.

```
" Add c snippets to Arduino
let g:snipMate = {}
let g:snipMate.scope_aliases = {} 
let g:snipMate.scope_aliases['arduino'] = 'arduino,c'
```

I am using this with the [arduino snippets](https://github.com/sudar/vim-arduino-snippets) that I created.

Answer (score 2):

@Sudar: Your approach is good but it's not necessary if you have a another config or lang later, your vimrc will be bloated.

just create `arduino.snippets` in snipmate then `:set ft=c.arduino` . Snipmate identifies snippets due to its filetype

Comment: I read about this also in the documentation. But then the problem is that I already have a couple of other autocmd for "arduino" filetype. Changing it to "c.arduino" will affect them as well.

Answer (score 1):

You asked specifically about snipmate, so this may be somewhat off the mark, but anyhow: there's also a plugin called UltiSnips that is quite similar to snipmate (with some additional functionality). In UltiSnips' snippet files you can use the extends statement that does exactly what you asked for.

Comment: I have not used UtiSnips, but I am quite happy with snipmate, so may continue to it.

Answer (score 0):

No. You need to yank/paste those snippets over to your arduino.snippets file.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to the `$VIMRUNTIME/after/plugin/snipMate.vim` file:

```
call ExtractSnipsFile(g:snippets_dir.'arduino.snippets', 'c')
```

This will parse and initialize the `arduino.snippets` file for `.c` filetype.

Basically it just loads the snippets from that file, and adds them to the specified filetype, in your case `c` file.

For help about using `ExtractSnipsFile` see `:help ExtractSnipsFile` [or see the Doc file on GitHub](https://github.com/msanders/snipmate.vim/blob/master/doc/snipMate.txt#L188)

**EDIT 2018.03.14**

It is possible to load multiple snippet files for the same filetype using `UltiSnipsAddFiletypes`.
If, for an example, you want to load `.c` snippets when editing an `.arduino` file, just add the following line to your `ftplugins/arduino.vim`:

`UltiSnipsAddFiletypes arduino.c`

Comment: Is this file part of vim-snipmate or I have to create a separate file and just only this line? Also if you can throw some light on how this works that will be helpful as well.

Comment: I am using [Vim snipmate](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate/) which is a fork of [snipmate](https://github.com/msanders/snipmate.vim). `ExtractSnipsFile` seems to be available only in snipmate.vim and not in vim-snipmate

Comment: Disregard my answer then, your answer is probably the best way to go then, and configure the plugin without editing any of the plugin files.